# Python parse text help- beginner

Tags: python, coding-style

I have only used Linux/ Python for a couple weeks so I am very new at this. I have a large file that is named "python.test". In the file I am trying to write code so that it tells me how many times a certain word appears in the files. For example the word is help. I am using Linux with Python and have tried several methods but have all failed. How would I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please upload the code that you created (and that failed).

Comment: Please give us your code, and please describe exactly what you mean by "it failed." If there are any error messages you should provide them in full.

Comment: I would like to have the text to open and tell me how many times it says help- This is the code I am using- 
with open("python.test, "r"):
         contents = f.read().split()
print Counter(help)

The error message I get is it just says that the command is not found. I have the text file I want it to parse saved on my directory as well as the code. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your file should be a .py file (ie **YOURFILENAME.py**). Then to run it in the terminal type `$ python yourfile.py` Please upload the code, it could be caused by of many other issues too

Comment: This isn't *necessary*, though it is a convention. If nothing else were wrong, then the python interpreter would still work. Try `echo "print('hi, nerd')" > python.test && python python.test`